# XSLT - Build XML from parameters

Tags: xml, xslt

Im trying to build a XML from to parameters, named as: 
p_nodes: which will contain the data (string separated by comas) of the nodes for the xml 
p_data: which will contain the data (string separated by comas) of what is going to be inside the node.

So far I got this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="p_nodes"/>
    <xsl:param name="p_data"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">        
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($p_nodes,',')">  
            <xsl:variable name="elemName" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:element name="{$elemName}">                            
                        <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($p_data,',')[position()=$pos]"/>             
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applying the parameters:

p_nodes: number,address,name,numdoc 
p_data: 123,Principal Av,alberto,456

The output I got is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<number>123</number>
<address>Principal Av</address>
<name>alberto</name>
<numdoc>456</numdoc>
```

So its working fine, at this point.

What I'm trying to achive is the tranformation using upper cases to identified parent nodes like this:

p_nodes: DOCUMENT,HEADER,number,address,name,numdoc,/HEADER,DETAIL,description,/DETAIL,/DOCUMENT 
p_data: 123,Principal Av,alberto,456,example description

output XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCUMENT>
    <HEADER>
        <number>123</number>
        <address>Principal Av</address>
        <name>alberto</name>
        <numdoc>456</numdoc>
    </HEADER>
    <DETAIL>
        <description>example</description>
    </DETAIL>   
</DOCUMENT>
```

Please let me know if I'm not being totally clear with my question.

Thanks in advance guys!

-Keva

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*in case there is a parent node*"? There **must** be a parent node (more precisely: a root element) if you want to output a well-formed XML document.

Comment: Do you know the root element name when writing the XSLT? Then simply wrap your for-each into `<document><xsl:for-each ...>...</xsl:for-each></document>`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k as you said there always be a parent node. What I tried to mean was if inside the xml there were another parent node.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I do not know the name of the root element. The root elemnt(s) should be defiend in the input parameter as MAYUS for example then somehow in the xlst put these values as root elemnts. How to do that is what im asking for.

Comment: You're not being clear.

Comment: @michael.hor257k An xml can have more than 1 parent node. something like:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
 <header>
  <number>123</number>
 </header>
 <detail>
  <description>example</description>
 </detail> 
</document>

The tranformation I want to achive is place the parent node on the correct position. As you can see in my question all nodes for xml are inputs from a parameter, a way of doing this can be using Upper cases if the node is upper case it is a parent node and so on

Comment: :*if the node is upper case it is a parent node and so on*" I don't think that's going to work, because your parameter lists the nodes without any internal hierarchy. But if you think otherwise, edit your question and show us an example of how the parameter will look and how it should be transformed.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks you're right. I think its a little more clear in the question now.

Comment: No, it's not clear at all, because the second HEADER could be closing the first one, or starting a new one. Why is this necessary? If you want to transmit hierarchical data, why not use XML (or some other suitable established format)?

Comment: @michael.hor257k this part is intended to recive an input xml then using web services this xslt is called. Then the new transformed XML can be send to other service wich will be expecting a standard format to correctly process this xml. Tha's why I need to get a new XML from an input one

Comment: But your input is not XML. And I am afraid this is all the time I care to spend on this.

Comment: What process / applicaton is actually creating the `p_nodes` and `p_data` list and passing them to the XSLT? It might be simpler to change this application to just build  XML directly, rather than try and get the XSLT to do it.

Comment: Hi @TimC im using a service created on esb 4.8.1 from wso2 to recive the xml and then pass the parameters.